# What Does the Use of "S" Mean In Certain Contexts?

Tags: grammar

Examples:

Der Fall: The case. Fall(s): In case of.

Das Mittel: The means. Mittels: By means of.

As an English speaker, I think of an s as a "pluralizer." But in these instances, the meaning of the noun-s sequence seems to be a construction of "preposition noun of."

What are these cases an example of? To take off on a comment below, what does it mean that s is a "genitizer?"

And are there many more such applications?

Comment: If that "s" can be explained grammatically, it is probably not a "pluralizer", but a "genitivizer". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words you're describing are prepositions which originate from a noun's genitive. There are other examples:

- angesichts
- abseits
- betreffs
- längs
- mittels
- namens
- seitens
- zwecks

There are similar preposition which are derived from nouns but without the final *s*:

- anhand
- anlässlich
- anstelle
- aufgrund
- dank
- infolge
- inmitten
- kraft (meines Amtes *z. B.*)
- laut
- statt
- trotz
- zufolge

---

When nouns are followed by one of these suffixes: *-falls,  -teils,  -weise, -maßen, -seits*, then they are adverbs and have to be written in lower case too:

*Examples:* anderenfalls, bespielsweise, haufenweise, etc.